# I have converted a Json to XML file.And now requirement is to insert the values into DB using mulesoft.Can anyone tell me how?

Tags: xml, mule, hsqldb

I have used data weave to convert the JSON to XML file.Now I need to insert the data's in XML file into HSQLDB.Can anybody help me as I am completely new in Mulesoft.

Comment: Please read [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**Create a database connector and insert the data into your database.**

**Mule** has an in-built **[Database Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/database-connector)** which you can use to connect to your database. Follow the [examples](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/database-connector-examples) to connect to your database and make your regular CRUD operations.

Make sure that you have the correct driver installed as well. If you're using maven (which you should be), here is the repository for the [HSQLDB driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/hsqldb/hsqldb) artifacts.

Comment: i have used a database connector.Drivers are installed correctly too with all the database configurations.However the xml file is created in the format<xml><name>xxxx</name>...</xml>.and needs to be updated into database through db conector...The name column in table should contain the value which is inside <name> tag in xml and so on...Could you please help.

Comment: @AJ1991 Ok, Mule has some excellent in-built [transformers](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/mule-transformers) which you can use to transform your data into whatever format you need. You can also use the [Dataweave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave) transformer which you can use. Try that.

Comment: @AJ1991 Usually a mule database connector needs a List or LinkedList (or similar iterable, such as HashMap) to insert into the DB. Just transform your data into one of those types and you should be good to go. I'm not familiar with HSQLDB, so you will have to try things and come back with errors or specific issues (in a new question).